# How can I modify the value of this promise?

Tags: typescript

Below is my typescript code.

The `innerFunction()` takes a generic-typed argument and return a list of objects of that type.

```
type myType1 = [any[]];

type myType2 = {
    a: number;
};

type myType3 = {
    a: number;
    b?: number;
};

async function innerFunction<T>() {
    const r2: myType3 = {a:1, b:1}
    return [r2] as T[];
}

function outerFunction(): Promise<myType2[]> {
    let x = innerFunction<myType3>();
    return x
}

console.log("outerFunction() = ", outerFunction())
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
outerFunction() =  Promise { [ { a: 1, b: 1 } ] }
```

But I want to change the value of the returning data inside `outerFunction()`. How can I do it? I don't know how to access and modify the value that the Promise `x` contains.

Comment: `outerFunction().then(t => yourTransformFn(t))`

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. Promises are immutable, and while they can contain mutable things and you can mutate the wrapped values you a) are violating the expectation of immutability and b) setting yourself up for subtle bugs relating to the timing of mutation. Maybe if you gave some more info about what you're actually trying to do we can help with a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to your “outerFunction“ you tell you will return promise but you never do it. And why do you want to return generic typed array? What I understand from what you want to do, the better approach is something like following:

```
type myType1 = [any[]];

type myType2 = {
    a: number;
};

type myType3 = {
    a: number;
    b?: number;
};

function innerFunction(): myType3[] {
    const r2: myType3 = {a:1, b:1}
    return [r2];
}

function outerFunction(additionalValue: number): Promise<myType2> {
    return new Promise<myType2>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
          let { a, b } = innerFunction()[0];
          b = typeof b === 'number' ? b : 0;
          const returnValue: myType2 = { a: (a + b + additionalValue) }

          return resolve(returnValue)
      }  catch (e) {
          reject(e);
      }
    })
}

console.log("outerFunction() = ", outerFunction(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

At your inner function if you are wrapping your function with Async then you must use the await key inside the function.
You can format your code as:

```
function innerfunction<T>():T[]{
   const r2: myType3 = {a:1, b:1}
   return [r2];
 
}
```

While your outter function will be:

```
function outerFunction()<myType2[]> {
    let x = innerFunction<myType3>();
    return x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `innerFunction` returning a `Promise` you must first unwrap it to access the inner data.

You can do that [using the `then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) of the `Promise`:

```
function outerFunction(): Promise<myType2[]> {
    let x = innerFunction<myType3>().then(value => {
        // value will be of type myType3[]
        // change it here

       return value;
    });

    return x
}
```

or using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function outerFunction(): Promise<myType2[]> {
    let x = await innerFunction<myType3>();

    // x will be of type myType3[]
    // change it here

    return x
}
```